# dynamic content table in jsp page

Tags: jsp

I have a problem with a jsp page (I'm a novice).
In a jsp page, I wrote a table that is read from a database.
I write here the code of the page:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.lang.String"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date "%>
<%@page import="jord.ConnectionManager "%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% 
    String sql= "select numelencotrasm,dtelencotrasm \n"+
                "from fimand \n"+
                "where eser=2012 \n"+
                "group by numelencotrasm,dtelencotrasm \n"+
                "order by numelencotrasm";
    ConnectionManager manager = new ConnectionManager();
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        conn = manager.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
        rs=null;
        conn=null;
        response.sendRedirect("../index.jsp");
    }
%>
<form id="tabella1" name="tabella1">
    <input name="numelencotrasm" type="hidden" value=""/>
    <input name="dtelencotrasm" type="hidden" value=""/>
    <table width="275px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td class="TabellaTitolo" width="50%">
                Numero Distinta
            </td>
            <td class="TabellaTitolo" width="50%">
                Data Distinta
            </td>
            <td class="TabellaTitolo" width="50%">
                #
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%
        try{
            while(rs.next()){
        %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="<% out.print(rs.getInt(1)); %>"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="<% out.print(rs.getDate(2)); %>"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" onclick="javascript:setValue('<% out.print(rs.getInt(1)); %>','<% out.print(rs.getDate(2));%>');">
                    Click-me
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            response.sendRedirect("../index.jsp");
        }
        %>
    </table>
</form>
<script language="Javascript">


    function setValue(num, dt){
        document.tabella1.numelencotrasm.value=num;
        document.tabella1.dtelencotrasm.value=dt;
        alert(document.tabella1.numelencotrasm.value); //test
        alert(document.tabella1.dtelencotrasm.value);//test
    }
</script>
```

Well .. I now want to create a new html-table click on the line "#" reads data from the database passing the values ​​of the selected row.

I apologize for the basic English! :/

Comment: it is not advisable to have connection related code in jsp use servlets instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require following changes in the above jsp code:

1. Add action URL to your form.
2. Make a call to submit form, after call to setValue().

In the action jsp:

1. Capture the parameters submitted by the above page,
2. Process on them further for detailed data from your database,
3. Construct an html table, and fill it to display.

This is a simple solution given, thinking you just started learning.

**Update 1**:

> *I want to display an iframe that contains the date table2 on click of the table1.*

For this you need following changes in your current JSP.

1. Define action URL as another JSP. It shall be something like `action="targetPage.jsp"`.
2. Define target attribute value for the form as your `iframe`. It
   shall be like `target="nameOfTheIframe"`.
3. Define and place an `iframe` in the page as appropriately. It shall be similar to `<iframe name="targetIframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>`.
4. In the JavaScript `setValue` function write instructions to submit the form.
5. In your other JSP, receive parameters submitted by this form,
   process them and display result.

Comment: But if I do submit on the form will reload the page.
I want to display an iframe that contains the date table2 on click of the table1. It's possible?

Comment: thank you! Your answer was very helpful.
This is my first question on StackOverflow and I do not know if I should do something to close the question.

Comment: @user1418910 Not required to close. But if you have enough reputation value, upvote my answer as well.